# Laravel withTrashed only if parent is trashed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have comments section but i only want to retrieve deleted comments , only if parent is actually deleted

```
Invite::forWedding($wedding)->withTrashed()->with([
        "comments" => function ($query) {
            // I want to check that "Invite" is trashed , else return unfiltered;
            return $query->withTrashed();
        }
        , "comments.user"
    ]
)->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could query directly the `deleted_at` column in your parent table.

Maybe something like this:

```php
Invite::forWedding($wedding)->withTrashed()->with([
        "comments" => function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('comments.deleted_at');
            $query->whereNotNull('invites.deleted_at');
        }
        , "comments.user"
    ]
)->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: This won't work because i want to check for "invite" status ( includes trashed or not ) before pulling the comments ( includes trashed  or not ). This will pull the comments only if invite is not trashed.

Comment: whereNotNull means where invite has been trashed if the deleted_at column is not null, the invite is trashed... as i said in the code comments you could use a whereRaw and implement your logic, i think that querying invite.deleted_at is a start to what you need... certainly is not the 100% accurate answer, since i didn't understand the question very well.